# Finding Missing Number in String with comma separated integer values in java

Tags: arrays

I have String with 1 to 100 unique numbers with (,) comma separated values like below and I missed one number in that. so how to find out that missing number.

Ex:- String s="1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, ..... 100";

/* here 6 is missed in that above string so how I can find that missing 6 value by using core java program */

Comment: What have you tried? Please post some code you've written so we're not doing your homework for you.

Comment: Thank you for giving replay, sorry I have not posted what I tried here is my code.        public class MissingNumberInString {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  boolean anyMissing=false;
   
  String s1="1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10";/* here 5 is missing */
  
  String[] s2=s1.split(",");
  
  for(int i=0; i<s2.length; i++){
   
   System.out.print(s2[i]+" ");
   
   if(s2[i]+1 != s2[i]){
    System.out.println(s2[i]);
   
   }
  }
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

If the list of integers is sorted, iterate over it and compare the values to their numeric index keys. as soon as one is off-by-one, you know which number is missing, and also what the position in the array is.

Answer (score 0):

When you are iterating over the string, check if the next number in the string is +1 of the last number.

```
anyMissing = false;
...
if (lastNumber+1 != currentNumber) anyMissing = true; 
// or simply print the number or something
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  String s="1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8";
  int sum = 0;
  int lastNumber = 0;


for (String str : s.split(",\\s+")) {
  lastNumber = Integer.parseInt(str);
  sum += lastNumber;
}
System.out.println((lastNumber * (lastNumber + 1) /2) - sum);
  }
}
```